# Messy HTAccess File Gives Duplicate Homepage

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following HTAccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?name=404

RewriteEngine on

# Add www. to any link without it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Set homepage
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite content pages
RewriteRule ^sub1/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/$ index.php?sub1=1&name=$1
RewriteRule ^sub2/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/$ index.php?sub2=1&name=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/$ index.php?name=$1

# Make the pages without .php work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This has gradually had bits and bobs tacked onto it and I now have a really small change to make, but can't work out how to do it.

The rules are basically there to ensure that all page have www and end in a /.

Most pages are in the form www.mydomain.co.uk/page/ which actually goes to mydomain.co.uk/index.php?name=page. There are two subdomains which pass an extra get param to the index.php.

The problem is that the homepage can be accessed from either www.mydomain.co.uk/ or www.mydomain.co.uk/index/.

How can I modify these rules so that if the user enters www.mydomain.co.uk it redirects to www.mydomain.co.uk/index/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the modification below to your .htaccess

```
### Existing Rules
# Add www. to any link without it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

##New Rules
#if request for www.mydomain.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.co\.uk$
#and it is for the home page, then redirect to index
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/index/ [L,R=301]

##Other Existing rules go here
```